# What does this code portion mean?

Tags: matlab

I came across this code portion:

```
file = imread(files(i).name);
file = file(1:1800, 520:2000, :);
```

What is the *second* line trying to tell us? Is it trying to assign "red", "green", and "blue" values? What does the last `:` represent here?

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing#1970s:_MATLAB

Answer (score 3):

`imread` returns an image represented by a `n x m x 3` array.

`file(1:1800, 520:2000, :)` extracts a rectangle out of this array, namely the first 1800 rows and the columns with index between 520 and 2000.

The last `:` tells MATLAB to select all channels for the extracted rectangle. Try replacing by e.g. `1` and you'll see a black&white image when passing `file` to `imshow`.

Answer (score 1):

After the call to `imread`, the variable `file` is a 3D array, where each of the 3 dimensions represent:

1: Height

2: Width

3: Number of color bands.

Therefore calling this:

```
file = file(1:1800, 520:2000, :);
```

actually crops the image so that it is now 1800 x (2000 - 520 + 1) x Whatever.

The last `:` ([colon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html?refresh=true)) means that you want to get all the values corresponding to that dimension, i.e. the red, green and blue color if that's a RGB image.

Answer (score 0):

After the assignation on your second line, the value of file will be replaced by:
-The values from the 1st to the 1800th cell of the previous definition of the first cell of "file" for the first cell

-The values from the 520th to the 2000th cell of the previous definition of the second cell ok"file" for the second cell

-All of the values from the previous definition of "file" for the thrid cell.

The `:` means all of the data, while the `1:1800` means "from 1 to 1800"